# Find normal subgroup with given properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $L,J,H$ be normal subgroups of $G$ such that
> $L<J<H$ and $|H/J|=p$ and $J/L=q$ with $p,q$ being primes such that  $p>q$.
> Prove that there exists a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $L<K<H$
> and $|H/K|=q$ and $|K/L|=p$.

**Attempt:** Consider the group $H/L$. Clearly it has order $pq$. Using Sylow's theorems we conclude that it has exactly one (normal) Sylow $p$-subgroup. From the correspondence theorem this sylow subgroup is of the form $K/L$ where $L<K<H$, $K\triangleleft H$ and $|H/K|=q$. Now it's easy to verify that $|K/L|=p$. The problem is that we cannot guarantee that $K$ is normal in $G$. I thought about proving that $K$ is a fully invariant subgroup of $H$ (since $K/L$ is a fully invariant subgroup of $H/L$) but couldn't get any further.

Comment: Are we assuming that $G$ is finite?

Comment: @RobertShore It isn't specified so I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: You are right to prove that $K$ is characteristic in $H$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I'll give it another go. Thanks

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I think I got it. $K/L$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup. Now let $\phi \in Aut(H)$. Then $\phi(K)\simeq K$ and $[H:K]=[H:\phi(K)]$ so by correspondence $|K/L|=|\phi(K)/L|$. By uniqueness, $\phi(K)/L=K/L$ so $\phi(K)=K$ and we are done. Is this correct?

Comment: If a Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal (i.e., unique) it is always fully invariant. Yes, that is all you need.